# how to stop images from moving untill the Click me button is clicked in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
var pic1;
var pic2;
var pic3;
let button;
let posX=0
let posY=0
const rightwall=350;
const height=600;

function preload(){
  pic1=loadImage("5.png")
  pic2=loadImage("iron.jpg")
  pic3=loadImage("slagmetal.jpg")
  
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(0);
  button =createButton('CLICK ME');
  button.position(0,0);
  button.mousePressed(changeBG);
}
function changeBG() {
  let val = random(255);
  background(val);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(mouseX + "," + mouseY, 20, 20);

 
  img1=image(pic1, 300, 30, 150, 200)
  img2=image(pic2, posX, 70, 100, 100)
  img3=image(pic3,posX, posY-300,150, 200)
  

  posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
  posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
}
```

I have created animations of three images and also added a button named as "click me" .how can i perform an event if i click on the button and after that the images start moving or animating.the images are animating on its own .i want to know how could i code so that after clicking on the button image will start moving.images will not move untill and unless clickme button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- use `loop()` and `noLoop()` methods: in `setup()` add `noLoop()` and in `changeBG()` add `loop()`
- use a global variable `playAnim` initialized false, change it to true in `changeBG()` and in the `draw()` function, add:

```
if (playAnim) {
  posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
  posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-50)
}
```

Comment: which code should i use so that it continues again and again on clicking thhe button.it stops after first time clicking and then again i have to refresh it